# ¿Por que no me aparece la opcion esamblado en el administrador de referencias?

Tags: wpf, c#-8.0, visual-studio-2022

Comunidad.

Estoy haciendo un programa con C# y Sql Server 2019 y Visual Studio 2022
en el administrador de referencias  no me aparece la opcion de emsamblados en la CapaData
en la clase conexion para agregar System.configuration solo aparece en la CapaPresentacion  alguien sabe ¿Por que?

Quiero agregarlo para hacer la conexion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema que tú, no divisaba el Ensamblador en el Administrador de Referencia para incluir `System.Configuration`.

¿Cómo lo solucioné?

Eliminé la CapaDatos en el Explorador de Soluciones y volví a crear la Clase CapaDatos y me apareció Referencias en el Explorador cosa que antes no me sucedió.

Espero te sirva de solución, porque a mi me daba error al incluir `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString`. Saludos